# T-SQL Server 2012 Dividing a grouped count by a total of the grouped account

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to get percentage result for each row where the grouped count for that row is divided by the overall total of all rows as per example:

[image: Balloons]

so I end up with the SUM column as Balloon row percentage of the total.

```
SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR, Balloons) AS [Year],
    COUNT(Balloons) AS [Balloons],
    SUM = (SELECT COUNT(Balloons)
        FROM TABLE 
        WHERE col2 BETWEEN  '20000101' AND '20160101'
    ) 
FROM TABLE
WHERE col2 BETWEEN  '20000101' AND '20160101'
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, Balloons) 
ORDER BY COUNT(Balloons)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  [Year], [Balloons], ROUND(CAST([Balloons] AS REAL) / CAST([SUM] AS real) * 100 ,3)  AS [%] FROM (

SELECT      
             DATEPART(YEAR, Balloons) AS [Year]
            ,COUNT(Balloons) AS [Balloons]
            ,SUM = (SELECT COUNT(Balloons) FROM TABLE WHERE col2 BETWEEN '20000101' AND '20160101') 

FROM    TABLE

WHERE col2 BETWEEN '20000101' AND '20160101' 

GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, Balloons) 

) AS d
GROUP BY [Balloons], [Year], [SUM]

ORDER BY [Year]
```

[Balloons Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44sXz.png):

```
Results

    Year   Balloons  %
1   2010   2         0.009
2   2011   1         0.005    
3   2012   1815      8.613
4   2013   5022      23.831
5   2014   7742      36.739
6   2015   6491      30.802
```